# Как сгенерировать рандом на один раз?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

У меня есть TextView и кнопка, при нажатии которой текст меняется рандомно с каждым нажатием на кнопку
Мне нужно чтоб текст поменялся один раз, следующие нажатие он не меняется

Comment: А начальное состояние, до первого нажатия - неизвестно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создай переменную `boolean isClicked` со значением `false`, в обработчике нажатий напиши примерно такое:

```
if (!isClicked) {
    генерируй число и ставь в текст
    isClicked = true
}
```

Comment: Работает, большое спасибо